# unallocated space within partition

Tags: gparted

150.00 GiB of unallocated space within the partition.
To grow the file system to fill the partition, select the partition and choose the menu item:
Partition --> Check.

(I can't click on the check option)

I got this warning after my pc accidentally shut down whilst shifting the partition form right to left side of unallocated space and then extending the partition.
Fortunately no data was lost, but now this error message is showing. please help

[image]

Comment: In order to use "Partition -> Check", the partition must not be in use (the key icon beside the partition indicates that the partition is in use).  Hence unmount the partition first.

Answer (score 1):

You're extremely lucky not to have lost any data...  If I were you, I would:

*Take a file back-up of all my files, delete the partition and then re-create the partition and restore the files.*

For more info [read here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) for user type 4.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to unmount the partition. (It is shown mounted in the screenshot above). In the Gparted window, Right Click on the selected partition /dev/sdb1 and click "Unmount".

Here, you can do two things:

1. **Shrink Partition**: To do this, Right click on selected partition and click resize, then drag the partition marker to the left. you will be left with unallocated space in the right, which you can use to make another partition on the device.

NOTE: as you said that you met a system shutdown during partition resize and this one happened. There is a possibility that you have already lost one partition. Usually, /dev/sdb1 should appear before /dev/sdb2 in the partition list.

2. **Grow Partition**: To do this, Right click on selected partition and click "Check". It will merge the unallocated space to the same partition i.e. /dev/sdb2.

In general, Grow is considered safe than Shrink.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar problem with **ext4** filesystem after a normal Ubuntu installation. I found the answer in this link - [How to grow filesystem to use unallocated space in partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289099/how-to-grow-filesystem-to-use-unallocated-space-in-partition)

As per recommendation in the above link, "See the man page for **resize2fs** (which is the command-line tool gparted will use to grow an ext2, ext3, and ext4 filesystem) for more details about resizing those filesystems."

As also stated in one of the posts, "Simply use **sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1** etc.,even while the filesystem is mounted, to grow it to the partition size."

Comment: Read questions carefully. The partition is NTFS, so `resize2fs` can't help here.